# AWS Load Balancer host rule

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I am having troubles to configure the rules of a load balancer.
I already have rules based on the path of the request and they work just fine.
I would like to add a security layer and filter the incomming requests with the domain's name, the goal is to allow a list of domains that can access the load balancer, and to return a 404 error otherwise.

I have looked at this documentation :
*https://aws.amazon.com/fr/blogs/aws/new-host-based-routing-support-for-aws-application-load-balancers/*

It is pretty straight forward but it doesn't work in my case and I can't figure it out...

Here is a screenshot of my rules configuration :
[image]

When I try this request `test.domain-name.com/test` in postman, it returns a 404 error like expected, but with the right domain it also returns a 404.

I edited the rule with *.domain-name.com and it works with the domain name but the request is also working in postman, which is not the expected behavior.

Does anyone have the same problem ?
Did I miss something ?

Thanks,